# Trigger for std::map operation

Tags: c++, stl

I want to implement something like `maplistner` in c++ for `std::map`. So  when a key is added or updated in `std::map` it should trigger a function or object.

It should be as:

```
class MapListener : public std::map
    {

    // ----- MapListener methods---

    public:
        // Invoked when a map entry has been inserted.        
            virtual void entryInserted();

        // Invoked when a map entry has been updated.        
            virtual void entryUpdated();

        // Invoked when a map entry has been removed.
            virtual void entryDeleted();
    };
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You would have to overload the functions which insert, update or delete entries.

Comment: Are you sure you need this? C++ isn't Java.

Comment: why would a `MapListener` inherit from `std::map` ?!?

Comment: @tobi303 because he would have to overload the `std::map` functions

Comment: @JakeFreeman, he could also wrap the std::map, then wrap the std::map functions (which is the correct solution).

Comment: @JakeFreeman isnt the `MapListener` the one who is supposed to get called when the map changes?

Comment: Yes but the only way to do this is to call the methods in the map functions

Comment: @JakeFreeman but that's the job of a `MapPublisher` or whatever, not that of the listener?

Comment: Please don't inherit from standard containers. They aren't made to be virtual... Since you're changing the class I must assume that your code is the only one which will interface with the `map` making the appropriate call where the `map` is worked with makes far more sense.

Answer (score 3):

Solution

(I am not advocating you should do this, just showing how to do so, because this sounds very much like the x-y problem to me).

```
template<class Key, class T, class Compare = std::less<Key>>
class EventMap final
{
public:

    EventMap(): data_{}
    {}

    // std::map::insert looks like this:
    // std::pair<iterator,bool> insert( const value_type& value );

    using insert_callback = void (const value_type& inserted);

    void on_insert(insert_callback* cb)
    {
        on_insert_ = cb;
    }

    // wrapped insert:
    void insert(const value_type& value)
    {
        data_.insert(value);
        if(on_insert_)
            (*on_insert_)(value);
    }

    // TODO: add similar code for other methods w/ callbacks
private:
    std::map<Key, T, Compare> data_;
    insert_callback *on_insert_ = nullptr;
};
```

client callback:

```
auto on_insertion(const auto& kv)
{
    std::cout << "inserted: " << kv.first << ", " << kv.second << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    EventMap<std::string, std::string> map;
    map.on_insert(&on_insertion);
    map.insert({"123", 123}); // will call on_insertion after inserting
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I got the idea.

Answer (score 2):

I apologise for blatantly ripping off @utnapistim solution, but the original would not compile. Nevertheless I find it interesting and would like to share working version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

template<class Key, class T, class Compare = std::less<Key>>
class EventMap final
{
public:

    EventMap() : data_{}
    {}

    // std::map::insert looks like this:
    // std::pair<iterator,bool> insert( const value_type& value );

    using insert_callback = void(const std::pair<const Key, T> &inserted);
    using erase_callback = void(const Key &key);

    void on_insert(insert_callback* icb)
    {
        on_insert_ = icb;
    }

    void on_erase(erase_callback *ecb)
    {
        on_erase_ = ecb;
    }

    // wrapped insert:
    void insert(const std::pair<const Key, T>&value)
    {
        data_.insert(value);
        if (on_insert_)
            (*on_insert_)(value);
    }

    // wrapped erase:
    void erase(const Key &key)
    {
        data_.erase(key);
        if (on_erase_)
            (*on_erase_)(key);
    }

    // TODO: add similar code for other methods w/ callbacks

private:
    std::map<const Key, T, Compare> data_;
    insert_callback *on_insert_ = nullptr;
    erase_callback *on_erase_ = nullptr;
};


int main()
{

    EventMap<const std::string, std::string> map;

    auto on_insert_fn = [](std::pair<const std::string, std::string> const &kv)
    {
        std::cout << "inserted: " << kv.first << ", " << kv.second << "\n";
    };

    auto on_erase_fn = [](const std::string &key)
    {
        std::cout << "erased: " << key << "\n";
    };

    map.on_insert(on_insert_fn);
    map.insert({ "123", "456" }); // will call on_insert_fn after inserting
    map.insert({ "786", "101112" }); // will call on_insert_fn after inserting

    map.on_erase(on_erase_fn);
    map.erase("123"); // will call on_erase_fn after erasing

    system("pause"); 
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely *don't* want to have `: public std::map` in your class definition, because then there is *no hope* of keeping all of the ways of modifying the map contained.

What you will instead find is that you have one type for the client, containing the event handlers, and another type that wraps a `map` and delegates every action to it, plus calls the relevant handler function.

You won't be able to use this in lots of places where `map` would work, as to see modifications to values via iterators and `operator[]` you are forced to use a proxy for your `reference` member. Thus your `iterator` and `const_iterator` members don't satisfy `ForwardIterator` (and `BidirectionalIterator`). Thus you don't satisfy `Container` (and `AssociativeContainer`).

As an alternative to not being a `Container`, you could instead have a `value_type` of `std::pair<const Key, const Value>`, and simply require that modifications happen with an "erase-modify-insert" sequence.